# Writing a fast (array-operation) function that solves a function in one column to get the next function value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I have a DataFrame in which I want to define each column b entry by numerically solving an equation that uses the corresponding element from column a. For instance, the first entry, let $a[0]$ and $b[0]$ be the first entries of column $a$ and column $b$. $a[0]$ and a function $f(x)=e^x - a[0]*x^2$ are given. I want to define $b[0]$ by solving for a zero of $f$. The same function $f$ is used to define $b[1],b[2]$, and so on.

Currently, I am doing this entry-wise by using scipy's fsolve, via a for loop on column b's entries. This does work, buit it is slow and I have heard it is bad practice to use for loops for DataFrames.

I would appreciate any advice about how to create a function that is faster. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could have 0,1 or 2 solutions. What you would like as output in the 0 or 2 solution case? Do you mind to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Good point. There's a unique solution in my setting, but the function is complicated to write down. We can assume in this problem that the solution exists and is unique.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the case there's only one solution then you could start to play from

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import root

def f(x,a):
    return np.exp(x) - a*x**2

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":np.arange(1, n+1)})
df["sol"] = df["a"].apply(lambda a: root(f,x0=0, args=a).x[0])
```